# Export MySQLi query to XLS

Tags: php, excel, mysqli, export, export-to-excel

I created this little script for exporting MySQLi query to .xls with help of some tutorials. The tutorial used MySQL but I'm using MySQLi. The file is successfully exported and readable but it puts the data on the second row. Here is my code:

```
<?php
include 'connectToDB.php';
$table = "users"; 
$filename = "users_export"; 
$sql = "Select * from $table";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql) or die("Couldn't execute query:<br>" . mysqli_error(). "<br>" . mysqli_errno()); 
$file_ending = "xls";
header("Content-Type: application/xls");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename.xls");
header("Pragma: no-cache"); 
header("Expires: 0");
$sep = "\t"; 
$names = mysqli_fetch_fields($result) ;
foreach($names as $name){
    print ($name->name . $sep);
    }
print("\n");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
    $schema_insert = "";
    for($j=0; $j<mysqli_num_fields($result);$j++) {
        if(!isset($row[$j]))
            $schema_insert .= "NULL".$sep;
        elseif ($row[$j] != "")
            $schema_insert .= "$row[$j]".$sep;
        else
            $schema_insert .= "".$sep;
    }
    $schema_insert = str_replace($sep."$", "", $schema_insert);
    $schema_insert = preg_replace("/\r\n|\n\r|\n|\r/", " ", $schema_insert);
    $schema_insert .= "\t";
    print(trim($schema_insert));
    print "\n";
}
?>
```

Comment: What frustrates me about so many of these "tutorials" is that they completely ignore PHP's built-in [fputcsv()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) function, and normally go for a bad homebrew option instead

Comment: The headers are on the first row, data on the second row.... are you saying that you don't want a header row?

Comment: Sorry guys, it works fine now, maybe the error was that i opened it in LibreOffice. In Excel it works perfectly.